# An unexpected change occurred after the parameter value was passed

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

Runtime: lua 5.1 with openresty 1.17.8.2 compiled under x86_64.

When I excute code as follow, a strange error happened:

```
-- code.lua
local function _render_ini_file(agent_gen, uid, instance_data)
    local context = {}
    return agent_gen._render(agent_gen, 'realnode_ini', context, _get_realnode_ini_file(uid))
end

-- agent_gen.lua
local function _render(self, category, context, file)
    ngx_log(ngx_NOTICE, 'Render ', category, ' to ', file)
    return file_ex.write(file, self.renders[category].render(context))
end

-- file_ex.lua
function _M.write(filename, content, append)
    ngx_log(ngx_ERR, 'write filename: ', filename)
    local is_exist = libc_ex.file_exist(filename)
    local mode = append and 'a+' or 'w'
    local file, err = io.open(filename, mode)
    if not file then
        return _log_and_return_err('Failed to open ' .. filename .. ' for write: ' .. err)
    end
    if not is_exist then
        libc_ex.chmod(filename, libc_ex.S_IRWUSER)
    end

    local ok, err = file:write(content)
    if not ok then
        file:close()
        return _log_and_return_err('Failed to write ' .. filename .. ': ' .. err)
    end
    file:close()
    ngx_log(ngx_INFO, 'Write file ', filename, ' successful')
    return true
end
```

And logs as follow:

```
[notice] 25539#0: *16220 [lua] agent_gen.lua:45: _render_ini_file(): Render realnode_ini to /config/realnode.ini, context: ngx.timer
[error] 25539#0: *16220 [lua] file_ex.lua:42: _render_ini_file(): write filename: /config/realnode.ini, context: ngx.timer
[error] 25539#0: *16220 [lua] file_ex.lua:42: write(): write filename: /config/, context: ngx.timer
```

It looks like the value of string chanded itself when parameter passing. In addition, the logs at the error level are printed twice.
Any idea?

Comment: It is not clear from your code who (which line of your code) has printed the 3rd line of the log.  Do you have second invocation of `ngx_log` inside `_M.write()`? What is the code between the two invocations?

Comment: I updated the full code for write. I'm sure there's no other invocation.

Comment: The 3rd line of code was printed by another (unrelated) invocation of `_M.write()`.  Obviously this another invocation had another value for `filename` parameter.

Comment: Well, I found the problem. It is true that there is another wrong call being executed at the same time.